# ¿Cómo quito espacios en blanco en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, importación

Tengo una base de datos con varios registros que copié de Excel pero, al momento de insertar los registros, se agregaron espacios en blanco: 1 antes de cada registro y 2 después. Lo que me ocasiona problemas al momento de hacer consultas, pues no retornan nada por problemas con los espacios, ¿Conocen la manera de quitar todo los espacios extras?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! usa trim https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: No está claro cuál es tu problema. ¿Cómo has realizado esa importación de datos de Excel a MySQL? ¿Se ha ejecutado correctamente? No entiendo que introducir espacios en blanco antes o después de las sentencias INSERT haga que habiéndose ejecutado supuestamente bien luego no te aparezcan esos 200 registros. Lo que indican gbianchi y amilcar aplicaría a quitar los espacios en blanco dentro de los campos si los 200 registros se han insertado correctamente.

Comment: Hice una tabla, copie y pegué en la terminal pero me añadió espacios en blanco al final, ahora poder quitarlos necesito hacer un UPDATE por cada registro, es decir, tengo que volver a poner el registro pero sin espacios

Answer (score 1):

La función `LTRIM` y `RTRIM` en SQL se utiliza para eliminar los espacios en blanco de una cadena.

`LTRIM` elimina los espacios de lado izquierdo de la cadena y `RTRIM` los de lado derecho.
Ejmeplo:

`LTRIM(string)`

Éxitos!

Comment: Si ya me funcionó, muchas gracias, según ya lo había intentado antes pero no funcionaba y ahorita lo hice y funcionó asi: UPDATE tabla SET columna=RTRIM(columna)

Comment: Perfecto! Entonces marca la respuesta como correcta, así el otro visitante con la misma duda puede encontrar solución a sus problemas.